# Pesky NULL checkbox in SSRS report

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, checkbox

I'm using the ReportViewer control in a WinForms app.  How do I change the "NULL" checkbox text to anything else? (just right of 'Begin Date' in the below picture)

[alt text http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/1774/dropdowninssrspagerequi.png](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/1774/dropdowninssrspagerequi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer, and it's a bit ugly, but hopefully this will save you some typing if you ever have to do it yourself.  Implement the IReportViewerMessages interface like so:

```
public class CustomReportViewerMessages : IReportViewerMessages
{
    public string NullCheckBoxText { get { return "All"; } }
    public string NullCheckBoxToolTip { get { return "All"; } }

    public string DocumentMapButtonToolTip { get { return "DocumentMapButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string ParameterAreaButtonToolTip { get { return "ParameterAreaButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string FirstPageButtonToolTip { get { return "FirstPageButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string PreviousPageButtonToolTip { get { return "PreviousPageButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string CurrentPageTextBoxToolTip { get { return "CurrentPageTextBoxToolTip"; } }
    public string PageOf { get { return "PageOf"; } }
    public string NextPageButtonToolTip { get { return "NextPageButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string LastPageButtonToolTip { get { return "LastPageButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string BackButtonToolTip { get { return "BackButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string RefreshButtonToolTip { get { return "RefreshButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string PrintButtonToolTip { get { return "PrintButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string ExportButtonToolTip { get { return "ExportButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string ZoomControlToolTip { get { return "ZoomControlToolTip"; } }
    public string SearchTextBoxToolTip { get { return "SearchTextBoxToolTip"; } }
    public string FindButtonToolTip { get { return "FindButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string FindNextButtonToolTip { get { return "FindNextButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string ZoomToPageWidth { get { return "ZoomToPageWidth"; } }
    public string ZoomToWholePage { get { return "ZoomToWholePage"; } }
    public string FindButtonText { get { return "FindButtonText"; } }
    public string FindNextButtonText { get { return "FindNextButtonText"; } }
    public string ViewReportButtonText { get { return "ViewReportButtonText"; } }
    public string ProgressText { get { return "ProgressText"; } }
    public string TextNotFound { get { return "TextNotFound"; } }
    public string NoMoreMatches { get { return "NoMoreMatches"; } }
    public string ChangeCredentialsText { get { return "ChangeCredentialsText"; } }
    public string NullValueText { get { return "NullValueText"; } }
    public string TrueValueText { get { return "TrueValueText"; } }
    public string FalseValueText { get { return "FalseValueText"; } }
    public string SelectAValue { get { return "SelectAValue"; } }
    public string UserNamePrompt { get { return "UserNamePrompt"; } }
    public string PasswordPrompt { get { return "PasswordPrompt"; } }
    public string SelectAll { get { return "SelectAll"; } }
    public string PrintLayoutButtonToolTip { get { return "PrintLayoutButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string PageSetupButtonToolTip { get { return "PageSetupButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string TotalPagesToolTip { get { return "TotalPagesToolTip"; } }
    public string StopButtonToolTip { get { return "StopButtonToolTip"; } }
    public string DocumentMapMenuItemText { get { return "DocumentMapMenuItemText"; } }
    public string BackMenuItemText { get { return "BackMenuItemText"; } }
    public string RefreshMenuItemText { get { return "RefreshMenuItemText"; } }
    public string PrintMenuItemText { get { return "PrintMenuItemText"; } }
    public string PrintLayoutMenuItemText { get { return "PrintLayoutMenuItemText"; } }
    public string PageSetupMenuItemText { get { return "PageSetupMenuItemText"; } }
    public string ExportMenuItemText { get { return "ExportMenuItemText"; } }
    public string StopMenuItemText { get { return "StopMenuItemText"; } }
    public string ZoomMenuItemText { get { return "ZoomMenuItemText"; } }
    public string ViewReportButtonToolTip { get { return "ViewReportButtonToolTip"; } }
}
```

Then, use an instance of that class right before you RefreshReport:

```
                reportViewer.Messages = new CustomReportViewerMessages();
                reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

And that'll do it.  Notice I've left almost all the properties as meaningless strings, except the two (at top) that I care about.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the report and uncheck the 'Allow NULL value' checkboxes for those parameters. You can use the 'Allow blank value' without the additional checkboxes displaying.

Comment: blank isn't the same as null, I'd have to change all my queries?

Comment: Correct, it isn't the same. You may or may not have to change the queries, I can't say. You could always NULL out the variable by checking the LEN in your query. Regardless, it's the only way I know of to remove the box and still not require a value.

Comment: Also, I can't allow null for float/date.  So I'd have to do some parsing in the queries then too

Comment: It turns out, the customer changed their mind and wanted this method instead of checkboxes.  Whatever :)