# How to move null to a checkbox in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

My colleague has created some parameters in her `SSRS` report and allowed null values for these parameters:

[image]

In our web-portal it looks like this:

[image]

These nulls will indicate to the underlying stored procedure that we'd like either *all* Products or *all* User data returned.

In other reports that I have seen rather than saying "(null)" in the drop-down a check-box is beside the drop-down.

How do I change the report so the check-boxes appear?

---

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pesky NULL checkbox in SSRS report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072245/pesky-null-checkbox-in-ssrs-report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the muti-select option:

[image]

If it is, select "Allow multiple values".

**EDIT:**

In reply to the edit in the question: 
in the parameter properties, from the Data type, select "Date\Time", and "allow null value".
It's achive what you want.

Comment: nope - I mean the check-box that can appear to the right of the drop-down

Comment: I didn't get you, can you add a snap shot?

Comment: adding a screenshot now

Comment: the screenshot was random from the internet - not from my application. My application refers to Product.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter provides available values for users to choose, then the NULL will be a option in the drop-down list. If there's no available values for this parameter, the NULL will be a check box.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.